# what is the meaning of nn.ModuleDict{t: nn.ModuleDict(A) for t in B}}

Tags: pytorch

I find an interesting style in Pytorch, which makes me a bit confused.
The original code from Github is:
nn.ModuleDict({t: nn.ModuleDict({t: ChannelWiseMultiply(num_channels) for t in tasks}) for t in tasks})
For the very inside, we can get {t: ChannelWiseMultiply(num_channels) for t in tasks}. The style is not common since we usually use {} as a dictionary.

I guess both A and B are lists, where the author would like to repeat the operation in A (torch.nn.Modules) to enumerate B. Is this correct?
Moreover, is it a specific style in Pytorch, since we usually use {} as dictionary?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Much like how lists have list comprehensions (i.e.: `[i * 42 for i in range(1, 11)]` gives you the first 10 multiples of 42), there are also dictionary comprehensions. What you're looking at is a dictionary comprehension within a dictionary. It should yield a dictionary of dictionaries.